# How to rename links using php

Tags: php

I have a link that shows

`www.mysite.com/product.html?id=2`

I want this to be renamed as

`www.mysite.com/product/product-name/`

or

`www.mysite.com/product-name/`

How can this be done using PHP?

Comment: It would be better if you do this in apache via url rewriting

Comment: Is there a link you can provide me to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a **htaccess** file or add the rules to your **vhosts** file.

Have a look at the [apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) docs. That can be a little confusing so here are some [examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be better to edit the `.htaccess` file.

You can generate your file [Here](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php) if you really don't know how to.